# TrueCrypt system encrypted drive fails to load Windows

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, encryption, mount, truecrypt

I have full system encryption on my Win 7 Pro/64 hdd. I boot the machine and enter the TrueCrypt password, and Windows starts to load but fails with the error message "The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible". I tried the below solution (taken from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/468284/150988)) and all went well until step 6. I do not receive any error messages when performing this step but the drive doesn't mount. Is there another way to access the drive after Windows fails to load? I no longer have the TrueCrypt rescue disk.

- Step 1: Plug in the hard drive to a computer with TrueCrypt installed.
- Step 2: Open TrueCrypt and click "Select Device" in the box where it says "Volume".
- Step 3: Select the partition that <strike>in</strike> (is?) encrypted and click "OK".
- Step 4: Pick a drive letter from the list then click "Mount".
- Step 5: After the password box pops up, click "Mount options...".  Check "Mount volume as removable media" and "Mount partition using system encryption without pre-boot authentication" and click "OK".
- Step 6: Enter the password and click "OK".
- Step 7: Right-click on the mounted device in the drive list and click "Open".

Comment: you can always boot from a live CD, and access the drive that way (or at least get better error information if it fails). I don't know of one that bundles it, but you can usually install software on live boots, as long as it doesn't require a reboot.